# ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION laravel.dev

Tags: laravel, networking, vagrant, homestead

So i came to the problem that my pc had to be refresched (win 8.1) So after that i re installed vagrant and virtual box as they were deleted. All homestead config files kept unharmed so i thought nice! let's install it quick and start developing right away. Unfortunately no. as i now get this : `ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION` whenever i go to laravel.dev:8000 my hosts file has :

```
#   192.168.10.10   laravel.dev
#   192.168.10.10   admin.dev
```

Does anybody know how to fix it!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the hash sign because any thing after the hash will be treated as [comment](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hosts.5.html).

```
192.168.10.10   laravel.dev    
192.168.10.10   admin.dev
```

Comment: ensure apache is listening to 8000, or php. Whatever server is hosting laravel.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, and for some strange reason, opening the `hosts` file and adding something to it (anything; like a comment for example) then saving it.. fixes the problem!

I had the same issue and this fixed it for me.

The only explanation is that maybe the Windows process responsible for handling/listening to the `hosts` file hangs sometimes and it needs the hosts file to be re-saved so it fixes the issues with this `ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION` error